# Is there any browser (Chrome, Firefox) plugin that allows to simulate geo location?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, geolocation

I need to test web application that extensively uses geo location api (getCurrentPosition, watchPosition). Is there any browser (Chrome, Firefox) plugin that allows to simulate geo location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly and you're asking for a way to fake geolocation responses for your web app, you might be able to do this in Firefox by overriding the `geo.wifi.uri` in the prefs, like Firefox's unit tests do. See:

- http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/tests/mochitest/geolocation/geolocation_common.js?force=1
- http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/tests/mochitest/geolocation/network_geolocation.sjs?force=1 - the [httpd.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Httpd.js/HTTP_server_for_unit_tests#SJS.3a_server-side_scripts) script responding to requests of the `geo.wifi.uri` used in the tests.

Comment: There is nice plugin that uses this method https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/geolocater/. However there is still problem with watchLocation, by some reason it is not updated.

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late, but **Microsoft Edge** has this useful tab `Emulation`.

You can open this developer tool as usual hitting `F12` button or by clicking on the browser's `menu button`, `Developer Tools F12`.

> **Geolocation:**
>   Simulate a GPS receiver and enter GPS coordinates to test location-aware features in a webpage.

[image: Edge Emulation]
[More info here at developer.microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/emulation/)

Answer (score 2):

Chromium 52 has it in-built:

1. Open developer console
2. Click the `:` button on the right, select `More tools` -> `Sensors`
3. In Tab "Sensors" you can modify the current location:

[image: chromium geolocation]