# How to Simulate HTML5 geo locations latitude and longitude for my webapp?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, geo

I thought this should be easy but somehow not able to get any solution for this. All i need is to simulate some Lat/Long on my browser so that My GEO Location enabled HTML5 app can consume my simulated lat/long and work accordingly.

Only positive response i saw on this forum was this post:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854959/how-to-simulate-latitude-and-longitude-values-in-my-browser-for-geolocation-tes#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854959/how-to-simulate-latitude-and-longitude-values-in-my-browser-for-geolocation-tes#_=_)
This didn't worked for me. Might be new FF doesnot supports it.
Any help would be great! Any plugin/service would do the job for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any browser (Chrome, Firefox) plugin that allows to simulate geo location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704706/is-there-any-browser-chrome-firefox-plugin-that-allows-to-simulate-geo-locati)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Firefox plugin that you can find here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/geolocater/

or this for Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/manual-geolocation/mfodligkojepnddfhkbkodbamcagfhlo?hl=en

Comment: Superb! I tried the FF one before and it didn't worked for me so posted. The chrome one worked and solves my problem. Thanks!